# Date translation automatisation

Tags: javascript, react-native, date, translation

I ask myself a question ... When I display a date that comes from my database (an array of my API) I would like to know if I can translate it.
What I mean is whether I can automate its translation. example: in English a date will have the format MM-DD-YYYY and in French DD-MM-YYYY
If in my API my date returns one of these two formats, can I display the other version if the user language changes.

Example in my case:

```
<List.Section 
    title={item.created_at.substring(0, 10)}
    titleStyle={{fontSize: 16, color: '#013243'}} key={i.toString()}>
```

This, returns : 2020-05-06
How can I manage to make it returns 06-05-2020 ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: There are already many questions on [detecting date formats](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+detect+date+format), pick any one as a duplicate. The bottom line is you can't do it reliably in general, you might be able to do it for a limited number of formats (i.e. special case). BTW, MM-DD-YYYY is pretty much exclusively USA, the rest of the English speaking world uses predominantly d/m/y, though some places use y-m-d or similar.

Comment: The obvious question is why is your API is returning dates in localised formats? The easiest solution is for it to use a single format, or failing that, send the format with the timestamp. Otherwise as you support more local formats you'll eventually encounter unresolvable ambiguities (hence the widespread use of ISO 8601 formats for data exchange).

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'm gonna check this out.